# Programmatically checking what Windows Phone marketplace the phone is coupled to

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

With the advent of the new marketplaces, Microsoft disallows certain language and content in certain marketplaces.

For example, the Chinese, Indonesia and Malasya markets do not allow references to alcohol - any references to alcohol.

One of my apps has a single string that contains the word "alcohol" in it and is thus disallowed. I was wondering if there's a progammatic way of discovering what marketplace a phone is attached to and thus remove the string in those cases.

I can of course submit 2 different XAPs to the marketplace, but I would hate the hassle of doing that.

Comment: Could you perform some checks against the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and exclude certain terms if the application is running in certain locales?

Comment: I don't think so - that can easily be changed on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to guarantee to return which marketplace the LiveID of the currently logged in user is associated with. Even if there was there would be no way to test this on the emulator, as it doesn't allow you to log in so you'd need multiple accounts, each with different marketplaces and to avoid the need to repeatedly hard reset your device you'd probably want multiple devices too. (THis may or may not be an issue for you.)

For your situation you'll need to submit multiple XAP files or remove the alcohol reference from all versions. The verification for this requirement is not done with devices associated with each marketplace but typically just done on a single device and so attempts to get around your situation in the way you've described wouldn't work.

Alternatively, you could localize the app appropriately and just not have that section in the localized versions for those countries. I'm not sure if that would be enough to meet the marketplace requirement though as users in those countries could still set their devices to another region/locale.

As a general guide, you could attempt to infer the marketplace the user is most likley to be connected to based on their location or regional settings but this wouldn't be guaranteed. Asking (to confirm) would be the best bet, but not in your scenario.